# Having a issue rewriting URLs via the htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm currently attempting to rewrite URLS for my employer's website for hopefully better results in SEO. However, I can't seem to get the url rewrite to work.

I have used this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myemployerssite.com.au$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/page-not-found.php
RewriteRule ^services/civil-construction$ /services.php?serviceid=1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I expected, for example, the first service  page which is civil construction to have it's URL to be rewritten from  https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/services.php?serviceid=1 to https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/services/civil-construction

But the URL remains as https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/services.php?serviceid=1

The redirect from non-www to www is working as intended as is the redirect from to http to https.

Some advice would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please clarify in terms of: "when user types (...) in address bar, I want the page (...) to be served, and I want url in address bar to (change to new url / stay the same as originally typed).

Comment: when the user types in https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/services.php?serviceid=1 or clicks on the link in the menu it goes/rewrites the url to https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/services/civil-construction

Answer (score 0):

I changed the order of the rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^services/civil-construction$ /services.php?serviceid=1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myemployerssite.com.au$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myemployerssite.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.php
```

Comment: Hi Jarek, Thanks for the advice but it still seems to not be allowing the rewrite of the url to occur. Also sorry about not answering yesterday I was unwell and away from work yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
RewriteRule ^services/civil-construction$ /services.php?serviceid=1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} serviceid=1$
RewriteRule ^services.php$ /services/civil-construction [L,R]
```

Comment: Error redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Still appears after clearing the cookies.

Comment: Then there is some other rewriting in place (maybe from app itself). What happens if you remove this rule, and try to open `/services/civil-construction`?